# How to convert USB driver from ext3 to ext2 without losing data?

Tags: filesystems, partition, ext3, ext2

This USB driver has two partitions, one is `ext3` and another `NTFS`. Now I want to convert the `ext3` partition to `ext2`, is it possible?

The partition has around 200G data and I have no spare disk or space to temporarily store that.

Comment: You can mount `ext3` filesystem with `ext2` driver, you do not need any conversion.

Comment: @sebasth, I have to convert it because this driver will be used sometimes on Windows PC, and the program for reading linux file system in Windows doesn't support mount ext3 as ext2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove journaling:

```
# tune2fs -O ^has_journal /dev/sdbX
# fsck.ext2 /dev/sdbX
```

Then you can simply remove `.journal` file.

Comment: Can ext3/ext2 store acl and other extended attributes? If yes, should we care about that?